# Multiplying values from arrays

Tags: php, arrays

I have a form that creates 6 arrays. They are heights and widths that i need to multiple.

```
Array1[0] * Array2[0]
Array3[0] * Array4[0]
Array5[0] * Array6[0]
```

I can get the arrays to print individually but I cant get the calculation to work.

```
extract($_REQUEST);
if(count($_POST)!=0){
    foreach($_POST as $key=>$value){
        if(gettype($value) == "array"){
            $i=0;
            $total = array();
            foreach($picw as $key=>$width){
                $total[] = $width * $pich[$key];
                echo $total;
            }
            /*foreach($value as $v){
                $i++;
                //echo "<div>{$key}{$i}: " . ${"{$key}{$i}"} = $v . "</div>";
                ${"{$key}{$i}"} = $v;
                $pic{$i} = $picw{$i} * $pich{$i};
            }*/
        }
    }
}
```

Here is what the array prints:

```
pich=>Array pich1: 12

picw=>Array picw1: 12

hungh=>Array hungh1: 12

hungw=>Array hungw1: 12

sliderh=>Array sliderh1: 12

sliderw=>Array sliderw1: 12
```

EDIT: Here is the form where the names come from

```
<form action="windowQuoteEnd.php" method="post">
        <table>
                <td colspan="3"><b>Picture Window Quantity:</b></td>
                <td><select name="picq" id="picq" class="dynamicAdder" data-selector="#pic_dup_1">
                    <option value="1">1</option>
                    <option value="2">2</option>
                    <option value="3">3</option>
                    <option value="4">4</option>
                    <option value="5">5</option>
                    <option value="6">6</option>
                    <option value="7">7</option>
                    <option value="8">8</option>
                    <option value="9">9</option>
                    <option value="10">10</option>
                </select></td>
            </tr>
            <!-- DUPLICATES BASED ON THE SELECTION ABOVE - NUMBERS INCRIMENT FOR EACH ADDED SELECTION WHERE THE 1 IS NOW -->
            <tr id="pic_dup_1">
                <td><select name="pich[]" id="pich1">
                    <option value="12">12</option>
                    <option value="24">24</option>
                    <option value="36">36</option>
                    <option value="48">48</option>
                    <option value="60">60</option>
                    <option value="72">72</option>
                    <option value="84">84</option>
                    <option value="96">96</option>
                    <option value="108">108</option>


                </select></td>
                <td> x </td>
                <td><select name="picw[]" id="picw1">
                    <option value="12">12</option>
                    <option value="24">24</option>
                    <option value="36">36</option>
                    <option value="48">48</option>
                    <option value="60">60</option>
                    <option value="72">72</option>
                </select></td>
            </tr>
            <!-- END DUPLICATE -->
            <tr>
                <td colspan="3"><b>Single Hung Window Quantity:</b></td>
                <td><select name="shq" id="shq" class="dynamicAdder" data-selector="#hung_dup_1">
                    <option value="1">1</option>
                    <option value="2">2</option>
                    <option value="3">3</option>
                    <option value="4">4</option>
                    <option value="5">5</option>
                    <option value="6">6</option>
                    <option value="7">7</option>
                    <option value="8">8</option>
                    <option value="9">9</option>
                    <option value="10">10</option>
                </select></td>
            </tr>
            <!-- DUPLICATES BASED ON THE SELECTION ABOVE - NUMBERS INCRIMENT FOR EACH ADDED SELECTION WHERE THE 1 IS NOW -->
            <tr id="hung_dup_1">
                <td><select name="hungh[]" id="hungh1">
                    <option value="12">12</option>
                    <option value="24">24</option>
                    <option value="36">36</option>
                    <option value="48">48</option>
                    <option value="60">60</option>
                    <option value="72">72</option>
                    <option value="84">84</option>
                    <option value="96">96</option>
                    <option value="108">108</option>
                    <option value="120">120</option>

                </select></td>
                <td> x </td>
                <td><select name="hungw[]" id="hungw1">
                    <option value="12">12</option>
                    <option value="24">24</option>
                    <option value="36">36</option>
                    <option value="48">48</option>
                    <option value="60">60</option>
                    <option value="72">72</option>
                </select></td>
            </tr>
            <!-- END DUPLICATE -->
            <tr>
                <td colspan="3"><b>Patio Slider Quantity:</b></td>
                <td><select name="psq" id="psq" class="dynamicAdder" data-selector="#test_dup_1">
                    <option value="1">1</option>
                    <option value="2">2</option>
                    <option value="3">3</option>
                    <option value="4">4</option>
                    <option value="5">5</option>
                    <option value="6">6</option>
                    <option value="7">7</option>
                    <option value="8">8</option>
                    <option value="9">9</option>
                    <option value="10">10</option>
                </select></td>
            </tr>
            <!-- DUPLICATES BASED ON THE SELECTION ABOVE - NUMBERS INCRIMENT FOR EACH ADDED SELECTION WHERE THE 1 IS NOW -->
            <tr id="test_dup_1">
                <td><select name="sliderh[]" id="sliderh1">
                    <option value="12">12</option>
                    <option value="24">24</option>
                    <option value="36">36</option>
                    <option value="48">48</option>
                    <option value="60">60</option>
                    <option value="72">72</option>
                    <option value="84">84</option>
                    <option value="96">96</option>
                    <option value="108">108</option>
                    <option value="120">120</option>

                </select></td>
                <td> x </td>
                <td><select name="sliderw[]" id="sliderw1">
                    <option value="12">12</option>
                    <option value="24">24</option>
                    <option value="36">36</option>
                    <option value="48">48</option>
                    <option value="60">60</option>
                    <option value="72">72</option>
                </select></td>
            </tr>
            <!-- END DUPLICATE -->
            <tr>    
                <td colspan="2"><button name="Submit" type="Submit" value="Submit">Get Quote</button></td>
            </tr>
        </table>
```

Here is the JQuery...

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function()
{
 $('.dynamicAdder').each(function(i,e)
 {
  var selector = $(e).attr('data-selector');
  var id = $(selector).attr('id');
  $(selector).addClass($(selector).attr('id')).removeAttr('id');
  $(e).attr('data-selector','.'+id);
  $(e).on('change',function()
  {
   var selector = $(this).attr('data-selector');
   var qty = $(this).val();
   var len = $(selector).length;
   for(var x=len;x<qty;x++)
   {
    var clone = $(selector).last().clone();
    $(selector).last().after(clone);
   }
   if(len>qty)
   {
    var diff = len-qty; // extra rows , delete them in the next step
    for(var y=0;y<diff;y++)
    {
     $(selector).last().remove();
    }
   }
  });
 });
});
</script>
```

Comment: Whats your actual `$array` definition is?

Comment: where are `$pich` and `$picw` coming from?

Comment: @CodeBird array names from form submit. See edit...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can loop over the arrays first and append their zeroth value to another array; then, chunk that value into 2 and multiply each to get your results.  This assumes that `$_POST` contains only the arrays you want to multiply and in the correct order:

```
$array_values = array();
foreach($_POST as $key=>$value){
    if(gettype($value) == "array"){
        $array_values[] = $value[0];
    }
}
$nested = array_chunk($array_values, 2);
$results = array();
// We know that the chunked arrays have only two values
foreach ($nested as $array) {
    $results = $array[0] * $array[1];
}
```

Or for the functional programming lovers:

```
$results = array_map(function ($array) {
    return array_reduce($array, function ($prev, $next) {
        return $prev * $next;
    }, 1);
}, array_chunk($array_values, 2);
```

Comment: Fantastic! Thank you!! One more question... How can I display each set of array in separate areas? I.E. section 1: array0 * array1 section 2...